# How can I hide the row of gridview if the value of column is "Kitted"?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, date, gridview

```
ID|name  |Status

1 |sample|Kitted

2 |sample|OnProcess
```

I want only to show the `OnProcess` value... is that possible?

I am using `VB ASP` and SQL for database.

Comment: So your expecting only one row `2 |sample| OnProcess`?

Comment: yes ... if i update the row 2 into kitted row 2 will also be hide .. its for request status .. if i accept their request the row will hide .

Comment: You need to provide code used to fill the dataGrid as well as you should state when/event you need to hide a row

Comment: `For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV_Tests.Rows
            If DGV_Tests.Rows(row.Index).Cells("Status").Value = "Kitted" Then
                DGV_Tests.Rows.Item(row.Index).Visible = False
            End If
        Next`  :         'what it do is iterate through all the rows in datagridview and change visibility of a row if it contains value _kitted_ in column _Status_

Comment: Protected Sub GridViewRequest_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridViewRequest.Rows

        Next
        If GridViewRequest.Rows(row.Index).Cells("Status").Value = "Kitted" Then
            GridViewRequest.Rows.Item(row.Index).Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub
this code im doing so far ..

error on row.index

Comment: You can make a simple select query like where status !='Kitted'